# Passing props to generic children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there way to pass props to a generic child (not a component that you know ahead)?

Something that would make `Wrapper` be able to pass `foo` to children.

```
var Wrapper = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <div>
            {this.props.children foo={2}} 
        </div>

    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Wrapper>
                {this.props.foo}
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czLym0nv/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine Javascript code

```
this.props.children foo=2
```

this is what your expression is transpiled into from JSX into plain JS. The fact is, you can't pass props to `children` directly because `children` isn't a React component. To make it work, you need to *map through children* and pass your props per every item of iterable.

The problem that comes next is that you can't simply do

```
this.props.children.map(child => (
  <Child foo={2} />
))
```

because, first, you'll receive TypeError because `map` is undefined, and second, you'd lose all initial props of every child.

You'll need to use `React.Children.map` static function as well as `React.cloneElement` to make it work:

```
React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, {
  foo: 2
}))
```

This way, every child element preserves its own props passed from parent element and, in addition to them, receive new props you define. Be careful with it because you may unintentionally redefine values of some props, too.

---

Your example code will then look like

```
var Wrapper = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        const {
            foo
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => React.cloneElement(child, {
                    foo
                }))}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Wrapper foo={2}>
                <div>I should be a component</div>
                <div>I should be a component, too</div>
                <div>We all should be components</div>
            </Wrapper>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot!